# SQL: count when value in one column appears in same row as another value from different column

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

Using the following data set, I want to find the average rate, while counting how many times the values in Condition and Intervention are in the same row together.

This is an example of the table I'm using:

```
Condition | Intervention | Rate of Subjects Affected
-----------------------------------------------------
Anxiety   | Drug         | 0.02
Anxiety   | Behavioral   | 0.05
Anxiety   | Drug         | 0.001
Depression| Other        | 0.7
Depression| Other        | 0.8
```

And I want to create a query where it will only count for the Anxiety/Drug pair once and find the average of the two rates it collected (.02 and .001)

This is the result I'm hoping for:

```
Condition | Intervention | Rate of Subjects Affected
-----------------------------------------------------
Anxiety   | Drug         | 0.0105
Anxiety   | Behavioral   | 0.05
Depression| Other        | 0.75
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas for this!

Comment: Do you actually intend for this to be tagged [pandas]?

Comment: Yes, I have the table in sql and in a pandas dataframe. Either answers would work

Answer (score 2):

Using `AVG()` aggregate function, you can get the expected result

```
SELECT Condition, Intervention, AVG(`Rate of Subjects Affected`) AS Rate
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Condition, Intervention
```